# Date range sets

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a question which is divided in two parts

**Part 1**

How can I get the following set of records with sysdate as current week?

```
07-Apr-2013 - 13-Apr-2013
14-Apr-2013 - 20-Apr-2013
21-Apr-2013 - 27-Apr-2013
28-Apr-2013 - 04-May-2013
```

If week is past 07-Apr-2012 - 13-Apr-2013, then next four sets. So always it will have 4 weeks.

**Part 2**

and if current week falls within the range of dates i.e. 07-Apr-2012 - 13-Apr-2013, I would like to get Monday and Friday from the list.

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the date ranges you provide in your example as the start date of each range is a Sunday in 2013 yet you show 2012 as the year.  I am going to assume the 2012 is a typo.

Does this get you what you want?

```
select 
case
    when trunc(sysdate) between start_date and end_date
    then to_char(start_date + 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    else to_char(start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
end
|| ' - ' ||
case
    when trunc(sysdate) between start_date and end_date
    then to_char(end_date - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    else to_char(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
end date_range
from
(    
    select 
        next_day(trunc(sysdate - 7 + ((level - 1) * 7)), 'SUN') start_date,
        next_day(trunc(sysdate) + ((level - 1) * 7), 'SAT') end_date
    from dual
    connect by level < 5
)
```

If you want just the 4 weeks then you can do this

```
select 
    to_char(next_day(trunc(sysdate - 7 + ((level - 1) * 7)), 'SUN'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
    || ' - ' ||
    to_char(next_day(trunc(sysdate) + ((level - 1) * 7), 'SAT'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') date_range
from dual
connect by level < 5
```

Comment: jwhite9 2012 was as typo, I have corrected it. I would like to start week on Sunday

Comment: And is possible to have as one entry  like `07-Apr-2013 - 13-Apr-2013`  `14-Apr-2013 - 20-Apr-2013`

Comment: The weeks do start on Sunday except for the first one, that one starts on Monday.  You stated that if sysdate falls within the range of dates you wanted Monday and Friday.  I updated my post to show you how to get the formatting you asked for.

Comment: You are right, my bad. How can I get this in `08-Apr-2013 - 13-Apr-2013` and second row `14-Apr-2013 - 20-Apr-2013`

Comment: I have created a view and then combined start and end_day to get `08-Apr-2013 - 13-Apr-2013`. Thanks a lot, appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  max(trunc(sysdate) + level - 7) as sunday,
  max(trunc(sysdate) + level - 2) as friday,
  max(trunc(sysdate) + level - 1) as saturday
from dual
connect by level < 30
group by to_char(sysdate + level, 'iw')
having max(trunc(sysdate) + level - 1) <= sysdate + 27
order by 1
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9620)

Comment: Egor, How can I sort it based on dates ascending? i.e. April, 01 2013 should be first.

Comment: @Polppan - Use `order by 1 asc`.

Comment: Egor I have tried that,http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9591m however it is not getting correct results, it is because it is converted to char?

Comment: Egor, Another thing is week should start from current sysdate, not from starting of the month.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1** (4 weeks starting with the current week)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')) || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+ 6) from dual
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+7) || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+ 13) from dual
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+14) || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+ 20) from dual
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+21) || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+ 27) from dual
;
```

**Part 2** Monday and Friday of the current week:

```
SELECT trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+1 "Monday", trunc(SYSDATE, 'DY')+5 "Friday"
FROM dual;
```

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9613).